# Does Spring Cloud Config Client support using Kubernetes as a discovery client?

Tags: java, kubernetes, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config, spring-cloud-kubernetes

I am running a Spring Cloud Config Client on Kubernetes. It uses `spring-cloud-kubernetes` and `spring-cloud-kubernetes-ribbon` dependencies for service discovery, and I am expecting it to be able to discover the Spring Cloud Config Server by setting `spring.cloud.config.discovery.enabled=true`, but it is not working.

**Background**:

I am trying to prove that Kubernetes' Service is able to replace the Spring Cloud Eureka for Service Discovery with minimum configuration.

I have deployed a Spring Cloud Config Server (named `config-server`, at port `8888`) along with a Spring Boot Microservice in Kubernetes as separate services in the same namespace, and used Spring Cloud Kubernetes' `@EnableDiscoveryClient` in the `Application.java` of both the config server and the microservice.

I have specified the following properties in the microservice's `bootstrap.properties` but the microservice always attempts to retrieve the config from `localhost:8888`:

```
spring.cloud.config.discovery.enabled=true
spring.cloud.config.discovery.serviceId=config-server
```

Only when I have replaced the above configs with the following, can the configs from the server be retrieved successfully:

```
spring.cloud.config.enabled=true
spring.cloud.config.uri=http://config-server:8888
```

Comment: There needs to be explicit support for that. Will you open an issue?

Comment: @spencergibb Thank you very much for your prompt response. May I know which project should I open the issue under? `spring-cloud-kubernetes` or `spring-cloud-config`?

Comment: spring-cloud-kubernetes